# Spring How casting dynamic type extends of Interface

Tags: spring, dynamic, casting

I begening to work with Spring Boot after 14 years in C# and litle issue over to be dificult now.

with activity:

```
@Component
public class GetBillingUserStatusActivity implements ITask<BillingStatus, 
String>, ITasks {

@Override
public BillingStatus Execute(String firstInput) {

    return BillingStatus.active;
}}
```

I have wokflow class that would execute the precedent activity like this:

```
@Component
public class CreateUserTokenWorkflow {

@Autowired
private ITaskResolver taskResolver;

@Autowired
private GetBillingUserStatusActivity getBillingUserStatusActivity;

public String CreateUserToken() {

    var task = taskResolver.ResolveTask(getBillingUserStatusActivity);

    BillingStatus response =  task.Execute("test");

    return response.toString();
}}
```

and my probleme is now on my TaskResolver class

```
@Component("taskResolver")
public class TaskResolver implements ITaskResolver {
@Override
public <T extends ITasks> T ResolveTask(ITasks t) {
    T type = (T) GenericTypeResolver.resolveType(t.getClass(), t.getClass());
    return type;
   }
}
```

T type = (T) GenericTypeResolver.resolveType(t.getClass(), t.getClass()) => casting to ITask failed

ErrorMessage: 
class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class com.consumer.workflow.manager.ITasks (java.lang.Class is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.consumer.workflow.manager.ITasks is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @211f766)